# What does it mean to divide an area by a distance?

Tags: applications

Let's say for example we divide 2m^2 by 1m, the result is 2m. What is the physical interpretation of this? I mean, dividing an area by a distance makes no sense to me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a rectangular piece of fabric has area $2m^2$ and one side is $1m$ long how long is the other side?

You might enjoy this
[droppings](https://what-if.xkcd.com/11/) xkcd. Read down to the line

```
Gas mileage is measured in square meters.
```

Comment: I did enjoy it. Thank you for the link. My confusion arose when I considered division as "how many equal things enter in the dividend", as the inverse of multiplication, it's much clear.